# jQuery Modal Box with Custom Buttons

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I need a plugin to display modal boxes with plugins.

Similar to something like when you add friends on facebook.

At this moment jQuery UI seems to be upto what I need

However I would like to know if there are any more possibilities.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have a look o [flowplayer](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/index.html) library

http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/overlay/modal-dialog.html